# how to customize google navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i was using sliding menu drawer it was awesome,and now switched to Google navigation drawer.but i don't know how to customize like font,color,gravity,spacing,etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Google's documentation? It explains it very well. You can define the layout (including font, color, margins, etc.) for the navigation drawer in XML like you would any other layout. Here is the link to Google's documentation and tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: there is no thing about use coustom font like arial or ... in Navigation Drawer Listview Items , is it possible to do ?

Comment: Fonts are done the same way they are anywhere else in Android, either programmatically or in XML. It's very possible to use a ListView, just add it to your navigation drawer layout in XML.

Answer (score -1):

Don´t forget about custimizing yours navigation drrawer listView! You could add very nice details with headers and so on.